# php expire page after pre-determined hours elapsed

Tags: php

I want to create a simple PHP application, through which students can submit their projects. I wish to set a timer (say in hours or even days), which when elapsed, the system automatically submits all the projects and disables the submit form.

Any idea of how I can set the timer and take action on page expire?

Comment: You can either run a cronjob to do it for you or check the elapsed time on each request.

Comment: guess checking the elapsed time on each request won't good, since i need the system to automatically trigger the action on time elapsed.

Comment: can i create cronjobs while still developing using my xampp?

Comment: What do you mean by submitting projects? Do you mean a form submit or a submit to an external source, like email or database? Furthermore, what do you mean by disabling the form. Should the page not be visible anymore or should just the submit not succeed. Please provide more information because the way you describe it there are very much things left in the dark.

Comment: If you're working on a Linux system / VM, sure. Dunno on Windows, but a cronjob is basically a set of instructions called upon a certain interval, in this case a plain php file should be called periodically and verify if the data is valid. Beware though that if you **really** want it to happen when the time elapsed, you'll need to do some dirty tweaks and use a cronjob to create the ones that will do the work, since the data will probably be dynamic. I would do it upon "user request". Why? Because it's irrelevant for the user when that data is treated or not, as long as it's displayed as-is.

Comment: ok, to make it simple, say we have 2 text fields, where each student needs to enter in 2 values (say, firstName and lastName) before 48 hours elapsed.

Comment: ignore my previous post, by mistake. let's say the lecturer creates a page which has 2 text fields, in which each students needs to fill in their firstName and lastName. the lecturer sets the time of submitting those 2 textfields as 48 hours. after 48 hours elapsed, the page should display "expired" and php should collect those values from a db and put them into another db, with emailing the lecturer.

Comment: I explained the solution before : `I would do it upon "user request"`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (PHP part):

```
<?php 
$till = mktime(...);
if (time() < $till) {
  if (isset($_POST['..'])) {
    // submit form
  } else {
    // show form
  }
} else {
  echo "Time's up";
}
?>
```

To submit all forms, i would do with the cronjob.

Comment: can i create cronjobs while still developing using my xampp?

Comment: Where is the $_POST comming from when run through a cronjob? What happens on the actual submit of data?

Comment: Maybe this would help you, how to create cron job on windows: http://drupal.org/node/31506

Comment: it just takes all the documents submitted from the database, adds it into another database, that's it.

Comment: @Boo you should call different file. Example: users posts on page1.php, cron job is calling page2.php. Also you can do this with $_GET in same file page1.php?studenPost page1.php?cronjob.

Comment: @user1021350: if you will have all files on your computer, then you can create cron job with running php file from command line. Students will not have access to it (http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php)

Comment: i have never actually created a cron job. as if a jargon to me. so, if any easy example?

Comment: Acualy i've never done cron job on windows. But it does not look very hard. 1.) create file that you want to call (cron.php). 2.) Open Start–All Programs–Accessories–System tools–Scheduled tasks. 3.) Double-click on scheduled tasks. 4.) Set up a Daily task that starts when your page will expire (+1min, to be sure that everything will be copied to new db. 5.) Tell the task to "run" this: C:\xampp\php\php.exe c:\xampp\htdocs\cron.php 6.) in the cron.php you must set that script can executes only on that day (if date('Y-m-d') == '2011.11.15') { /* export */ })